# Set FormField appearance attribute in the theme

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am working in an NX Monorepo and have a shared ui-components lib that implementes additonal functionality for Angular Material Components. However, I am using different themes for different applications and want to use `appearance='outline'` for a certain application.

Is it possible to define the `appearance` in the theme file?

My workaround is to create a wrapper component that sets the appearnce to outline, but I would like to archive this via the theme.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, I expect an outlined form field to have a different DOM than a filled form field. How about using the the form field default options injection token in the application where you want to use outlined form fields? For more info see the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormFieldDefaultOptions)

Comment: @JSONDerulo Thanks you. This works perfectly fine. Will post a minimal working example for others to check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @JSONDerulo for bringing up the hint with the injection token. Using

`{ provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'outline' }}`

in the providers allows you to set the appearance for a specific application or module.

See the docs here for more options: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS